# Real impulse response

Tags: impulse-response, laplace-transform, poles-zeros

It will be great if someone can explain me what exactly means "real impulse response".
Further more , what is the effect of such a response on ROC (Laplace plane) and in particular if its restrict the possible area of the poles and zeros?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> real impulse response

An [impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) that is [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Numbers)-valued.

> effect of such a response on ROC

nothing specific, since realness doesn't imply any kind of stability/convergence, far as I can tell. It does tell you something about poles and zeros always appearing in conjugate pairs, but that's it.

> restrict the possible area of the poles and zeros

no

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Well, the possible *values* of the poles and zeros are subject to only coming in conjugate pairs -- i.e., if you have a pole at $a + jb$, there would need to be a matching one at $a - jb$ for the impulse response to be real.

Comment: @TimWescott I feel like that's the second sentence of my second paragraph?

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Need to go back to 3rd grade and repeat the reading comprehension part of my education, apparently.

Comment: @TimWescott you're doing fine so far; it's probably just a erasure on reading my post, and then your FEC decoder kicked in